# Identity Server + Angular Implicit Flow Callback Error

Tags: angular, identityserver3

Seeing a really weird error with our Identity Server auth server and our #Angular application, using implicit flow.

First: our Angular applications are running in docker containers with NGINX also inside the container serving the application.

We have the clients for Identity Server set up with callback URLs, & this works in our local dev environments as well as test & (most of the time) production.

But we just noticed an error that has apparently been happening for a while but wasn't a show stopper until today. The important part of the Identity Server logs say:

```
Invalid redirect_uri: https://localhost:44311
```

in both the test and production environments, and have been for the past couple months. Like I said, until today it's not been an issue whatsoever.

The thing is, "localhost:44311" is not present anywhere in our code base; not in the Identity Server clients list, not in the Angular application, not in the NGINX config....I have no idea where it's coming from. Does anyone have any ideas of where to start on this?

Where could that reference of localhost:44311 be coming from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears the [angular-auth-oidc-client](https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client) package uses that as a default.

Comment: It turns out that, more specifically, we had silent_renew set to true, but then weren't overwriting the silent_renew_url and silent_renew_redirect URLs. Those were the ones that were defaulting to localhost:44311.